# C++ access constant value declared in cpp

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a main method in my `main.cpp` that I would like to display the value of a constant `int` I have declared.

I added a `DeclareConstant` class.

Here is my DelcareConstant.h

```
#pragma once
class DeclareConstant
    {

 public:
     const int x;
     Part1(void);
     Part1(int x);
     ~Part1(void);
     double getX(){return x;}
 };
```

And source

```
#include "Part1.h"

Part1::Part1() : x(55){
}
```

How can I access X so I can display it in my main method?  I need to check if I'm even initializing it correctly.

Comment: You have a `const int` that isn't initialised. I don't think this will compile.

Comment: `class DeclareConstant` or `class Part1`?

Comment: You might also think about why `x` is an int but `getX()` returns a double...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `x` through getter function `getX()`, for example:

```
DeclareConstant dc;
std::cout << dc.getX() << std::endl;
```

Or

```
DeclareConstant dc;
std::cout << dc.x << std::endl;
```

However, you should define your getX like this:

```
class DeclareConstant
{

 public:
     int getX() const {return x;}

 private:
  const int x; 
 };
```

And please hide your class member.

Comment: Why `getX`? `x` is a public member :)

Comment: `dc.getX()` is only one way... you could also list `dc.x` as it's preceeded by the `public:` access specifier.

Answer (score 0):

You need an *object* or an *instance* of `DeclareConstant` to access the `DeclareConstant`'s `x` member.

```
DeclareConstant myConst;
std::cout << myConst.x << std::endl;   // Use x
```

But for your *possible* purpose and intentions you could make `x` as a *static member*.

```
class DeclareConstant {
public:
   static const int x = 55;
   // ...
}
```

You now don't need an instance to get the value of `x`:

```
std::cout << DeclareConstant::x << std::endl;   // Use x
```

Comment: When I try to create an object, I get Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall DeclareConstant::~DeclareConstant(void)" (??1DeclareConstant@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain C:\Users\***

Comment: @AllenJames You need to *define* your destructor.

Comment: @AllenJames: you need to *define* your constructor.  You only declared it as a function which takes no arguments. Since you changed your code to create an instance of this class the compiler now needs the definition of the destructor, but it can't find it.  Declaration of a function; `class foo { int bar(); };`.  Definition of a function: `int foo::bar() { }`

Answer (score 0):

If all your instances use the same constant value, you can make it static. This has a couple of advantages.

You can define it as below.

class Part1{

public:
     static const int x = 42;
     Part1(void);
     Part1(int x);
     ~Part1(void);
     double getX(){return x;}
 };

and access it simply as `Part1::x`. You should make `getX` static as well, then you can do `Part1::getX()`.

This will not work if each instance has its own `const` value.